# CodeIgniter + jQuery UI autocomplete = 500 internal server error (with code) due to CSRF set to TRUE

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, csrf

Here is the view code:

```
<html>
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Load JQuery UI -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( function() {    

        $("#input").autocomplete({
            source: function(req, add){
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>test/ac2',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    //data: req,
                    data: 'input='+req,
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data.response =='true'){
                           add(data.message);
                        }
                    }
                });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui){
            $(this).end().val(ui.item.value);
            }
        });

     });      
</script>
</head>
<?php

echo form_open();
echo form_input('input', '', 'id="input"');
echo form_close();

?>
</html>
```

and the controller code:

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('vw/test_vw');
    }

    public function ac2()
    {

        //$search = $this->input->post('term');
              $search = $this->input->post('input');

        $data['response'] = 'false';

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('loc_exercise');
        $this->db->like('locations', $search);
        $locations = $this->db->get()->result();


        if (count($locations) > 0) {
            $data['message'] = array();

            foreach ($locations as $location) {
                $data['message'][] = array(  'label' => $location->locations,
                'item'  => $location->locations,
                'value' => $location->locations );
            }

            $data['response'] = 'true';
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

When I type anything in into the input box I get this on the console:

```
POST http://my.example.com/test/ac2 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

and on CI error logs there seems to be no issues (log_threshold is 1, /logs is chmod 777).

BTW I have my config.php with query_strings TRUE and allow_get_array TRUE.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly a CSRF token issue.

See [this in the CI forums](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/176318/) and this [blog post](http://aymsystems.com/ajax-csrf-protection-codeigniter-20)

Comment: you nailed it -- as soon as I turned CSRF off, the autocomplete dropdown worked as normal -- now I wonder how am I going to use CSRF... still haven't digested the solutions offered in that post on CI forum :P -- anyway thanks a bunch!

Comment: the blog post mentioned above by @coolgeek is awesome and nicely explains how to fix this problem

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in your question suggests that you need to turn `query_strings` on or `allow_get_array`

Try this

comment out this line

```
$search = $this->input->post('term');
```

then add `$search` to your function as the first argument

```
public function ac2($search)
```

Then just try to hit the URL with a browser

`http://yourdomain.com/index.php/test/ac2/<insert your search string here>`

**Now that we know your url is good**

change your controller back.

try this...

```
data: 'term='+req,  //<-- change to this
```

Comment: yes! doing that works and returs JSON data to the browser with decent matches -- but when I go back to my previous setup I still get the 500 on  console -- how do I get this to work as expected (ie, matches show as dropdown below INPUT)?

Comment: FWIW -- if I go back to previous setup (my original code above) and navigate to `http://yourdomain.com/index.php/test/ac2/` I get JSON data with all results from database

Comment: thanks for helping with this - unfortunately not working, still get the 500 -- I updated the code from OP -- you will see that now I use `input` as post key since that's the name on the form input -- I also simplified the `foreach array` and added your JS suggestion -- but it's still not working and I can't figure out why!

Comment: thanks a lot for helping out -- looks like the issue is CSRF tokens ON, see below -- cheers

Answer (score 1):

seems you are missing sendig the csrf token with the POST data,  try:

```
    $("#input").autocomplete({
        source: function(req, add){

    var cct = $("input[name=ci_csrf_token]").val(); //  <---

            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>test/ac2',
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                //data: req,
                data: 'input='+req,
    'ci_csrf_token': cct,   //  <---
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.response =='true'){
                       add(data.message);
                    }
                }
            });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui){
        $(this).end().val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });

 });
```

you can also find the token like:

```
     csrf_test_name:$("input[name=csrf_test_name]").val(),
```

that token is generated in the view when using the form helper and opening it like:

```
  <?php echo form_open();?>
```

sources: 
* http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/176318/
** own headache

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP code without the AJAX. Your error suggests that your PHP is the one that is causing the error.

One more thing it is quite better to see if you have results before you call `->result()`