# CodeIgniter + AJAX Internal Error 500

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to make a ajax call to one method in my Notification controller.

My method is:

```
public function testeAjax()
{
    if($this->chamadaAjax())
        echo 'Ajax';
    else
        echo 'Form';
}
```

The `$this->chamadaAjax()` simply perform and `$this->input->is_ajax_request()`

And this is my Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/office/notificacao/testeAjax',
      success: function(html) {
        alert(html);
      }
    });
```

I have a form with two buttons, one for form submit and another for ajax request.

The thing is that when I add some data to the ajax like: data: "nome=Gerep", and call it, I receive a `Internal Erro 500`

When I don't send any data, it works, it returns me *form* when submitted and *ajax* when I call ajax request.

Any ideas?

*EDIT*
Using FireBug here is what I get:

```
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.sendjquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
f.extend.ajaxjquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
testenotificacao:140
(anonymous function)notificacao:113
onclick
```

Comment: Did you check your server logs? If you have access to them the safest way to pinpoint the real reason is to check them out - there will be a reason logged for the HTTP /1.1 500.

Comment: You will be able to access the error log only if you use a dedicated or VPS machines. On shared web hosting server error log is usually not available (just the access log). Where to look for it depends on the distro (OS) running the web server. On RedHat derivates its in `/etc/httpd/logs/error_log`.

Comment: to avoid disabling CRSF see this thread

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355480/codeigniter-jquery-ui-autocomplete-500-internal-server-error-with-code/10794847#10794847

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with [Cross Site Request Forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery), disabling it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you managed to bash the server with a CRSF protection but in case you need to share content between domains [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) is the solution you need. Just define Origin policies on your web server and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the data in the URL or defining an object? I.e: Data being passed (especially POST) should look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/office/notificacao/testeAjax',
      data: { nome: "Gerep" },
      success: function(html) {
        alert(html);
      }
    });
```

and NOT like this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/office/notificacao/testeAjax?nome=Gerep',
      success: function(html) {
        alert(html);
      }
    });
```