# 500 (Internal Server Error) jQuery ajax ui autocomplete codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to access data using jQuery ui autocomplete. On my local host it was well done, but when I upload it to my server it doesn't work.
I get a console logs that says "`http://myweb.com/data/header/lookup?term=PO 500 (Internal Server Error)`".

I'm using codeigniter to build it.

Here's the jQuery:

```
$("#producttype").autocomplete({
  source: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>data/header/lookup",
  minLength: 2,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $("#productcode").val(ui.item.code)
  },
  change: function(event, ui){
    if(ui.item == null || ui.item == undefined){
      $("#producttype").val("");
      $("#productcode").val("");
    }
  }
});
```

Here's the controller:

```
public function lookup(){
  if (isset($_GET['term'])){
    $q = strtolower($_GET['term']);
    $this->welcome_m->get_word($q,'DESC1','10');
  }
}
```

Here's the model:

```
function get_word($q, $col = '', $param=''){

  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT KODE, DESC1 FROM MASTER WHERE $col LIKE '%".$q."%' AND LENGTH(KODE) = $param");

  if($query->num_rows > 0){
    foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
      $new_row['label']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['DESC1']));
      $new_row['code']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['KODE']));
      $row_set[] = $new_row;
    }
    echo json_encode($row_set);
  }
}
```

I need advice and help to resolve it, please.

Comment: Check the web server's error log for the cause of the 500 response

Comment: @Phil, i found there is error_log on my server, it say:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/htscanner.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/htscanner.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

need help please :(

Answer (score 0):

double check your servers database, if you are able to connect to the live database remotely, try and use an example of your query on the database itself and see what error occurs.

in your CI index file, change your 'ENVIRONMENT' variable to 'development'

this should allow errors to be displayed.

Try using CI's Active directory

```
$this->db->select('KODE, 'DESC1')
         ->like($col, $q, 'both')
         ->where('LENGTH(KODE) = '.$param)
         ->get('MASTER');
```

Comment: i have found the problem, it's about crsf. But still not work for my problem :-(

source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355480/codeigniter-jquery-ui-autocomplete-500-internal-server-error-with-code/10794847#10794847